# Combine date present in two different columns to generate mean for a column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset of the following format which has the Starting column values ranging from 2021-01-01 to 2022-03-13 and same goes for the Ending column where my values begin from 2021-01-01 to 2022-03-13.

The data for rainfall gets collected on a daily basis such that the entries are as follows:

[image: This is the format of the data in my pandas df.]

[image: Apologies for the format. I want to get the display of the new dataframe like this]

I am trying to combine and form monthly average values for the dataset. I cannot find a way where I am able to take monthly average values and store them in a different pandas dataframe such that it appears as follows:

The Monthly Rainfall is found using Total rainfall/ Total days in the month

Any help would be appreciated!

I have tried to use groupy and mean together from pandas library to find the output but it doesn't appear in the format I want.

df=df.groupby(['Starting','Ending','Location_id'])['rainfall'].mean().reset_index()

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, you can write a function like this:

```
import math
from datetime import datetime

def to_date(x, y):
  lists = zip([datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d').date() for dt in x], [datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d').date() for dt in y])
  return [0 if math.isinf((x-y).days) else (x-y).days for x,y in lists]
```

Basically this function takes two lists (x,y) and turn every item in those into `date()` objects. And returns a new lists with items as `days` object. For your information, if you deduct same dates, Python returns an `inf` integer, which is infinite. To go over this, you can check if the item is an infitine integer, if so return 0 else return `days`.

Here's the code snippet I wrote, since you didn't provide a dataset, I wrote using the images you provided:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'New_Starting': ['2021-01-01','2021-01-01','2021-01-01'],
    'New_Ending': ['2021-01-31','2021-01-31','2021-01-31'],
    'Location_id': [45, 52, 30],
    'Rainfall': [4.07, 6.53, 3.71]
}

d = pd.DataFrame(d)
d['Monthly_Rainfall'] = d['Rainfall'] / to_date(d['New_Ending'], d['New_Starting'])
```

Output:

```
    New_Starting    New_Ending  Location_id Rainfall    Monthly_Rainfall
0   2021-01-01      2021-01-31       45     4.07        0.135667
1   2021-01-01      2021-01-31       52     6.53        0.217667
2   2021-01-01      2021-01-31       30     3.71        0.123667
```